# Replace strings in a directory everywhere including file name

Tags: bash, shell

I want to replace every occurence of string a2b3 with a6b7 in a directory containing several directories and files. If this string occurs in a file name replace it there as well.
I am able to replace it in files using following code

```
    FILES=`find ./* -type f -name "xyz*"` 



for file in $FILES
    do
        sed -i 's/a2b3/a6b7/' $file
    done
```

what code should i add so that if it captures the same a2b3 string in file name of $file it should replace it there as well. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add:

```
for file in $FILES ; do
  if [[ "$file" == *a2b3* ]] ; then
    mv -- "$file" "${file/a2b3/a6b7}"
  fi
done
```

Note that it's a bit dangerous to build a string named `$FILES` and expand it this way, since any asterisks or question-marks or square-brackets inside can trigger filename-expansion, and of course the whole concept is broken if any file-name contains whitespace. (For example, if you have files named `a`, `b c`, and `*`, and you set `$FILES` to `'a b c *'`, then your loop will iterate over `a`, `b` (file-not-found), `c` (file-not-found), `a` again, and finally `b c`; and it will never hit `*`.)

---

**Edited to add** for updated question:

Now that we know that you're setting `$FILES` by running `` FILES=`find ./* -type f -name "xyz*"` ``, we can modify the above to fix this issue. One approach is to use `find`'s built-in ability to run arbitrary commands on the files it finds (instead of printing them out):

```
find -type f \
     -name 'xyz*a2b3*' \
     -execdir bash 'mv -- "$1" "${1/a2b3/a6b7}"' '{}' ';'
```

This fixes the case where a filename contains whitespace or filename-expansion metacharacters, and it also fixes the case where a directory contains `a2b3`.

Another approach is to tell `find` to separate filenames with null bytes (which can't appear in filenames), and pipe its output to a loop that reads the filenames and operates on them appropriately.

```
find -type f -name 'xyz*a2b3*' -print0 \
| while read -r -d '' ; do
    mv -- "$REPLY" "${REPLY/a2b3/a6b7}"
  done
```

Comment: In my script I got $FILES array  using following code :  FILES=`find ./* -type f -name "xyz*"`

Comment: @user1468315: Yeah, I figured. So, yes: you're susceptible to this problem. (And, `FILES` isn't an array. Bash does support arrays, but you're not using them.)

Comment: Yes I got it !! is there any alternative for this ??